# Unix File Protection Commands

Tags: files

```
 ~/UnixCourse
You should be able to add and remove files from the directory, access files within the directory whose names you already know, and look through the directory via ls to see what files are in there. No one else should be able to do any of these things.
(This is a good setting for directories where you will keep assignments for various courses. After this assignment, your ~/UnixCourse directory should always be set this way.)

~/UnixCourse/fileAsst
You should be able to add and remove files from the directory, access files within the directory whose names you already know, and look through the directory via ls to see what files are in there. People in your group should be able to do ls and to access files, but not add/remove files from the directory. People outside your group should be able to do none of these things.
(Actually, no one but you will really have access to this directory because it’s inside ~/UnixCourse and, if you’ve done the prior step correctly, they can’t get inside there to get to fileAsst. But, for the sake of this exercise, we’ll ignore that fact.)

~/UnixCourse/fileAsst/Empire
You should be able to add and remove files from the directory, access files within the directory whose names you already know, and look through the directory via ls. Everyone else should be able to use ls but have no other privileges.

~/UnixCourse/fileAsst/Alliance
You should be able to add and remove files from the directory, access files within the directory whose names you already know, and look through the directory via ls. Everyone else should be able to access files in the directory for which they already know the names, but have no other privileges.

~/UnixCourse/fileAsst/Empire/darth.txt
Everyone should be able to read and write to this file.

~/UnixCourse/fileAsst/Alliance/r2d2.txt
We will pretend, for the sake of this assignment, that this file contains an executable program. You should be able to read and write to this file. You and members of your group should be able to execute it. People other than you have no other privileges.
```

Here is my solution for this problem:

```
 chmod 700 UnixCourse
 chmod 740 fileAsst
 chmod 744 ~/UnixCourse/fileAsst/Empire
 chmod 666~/UnixCourse/fileAsst/Alliance
 chmod 670~/UnixCourse/fileAsst/Empire/darth.txt
 chmod 660~/UnixCourse/fileAsst/Alliance/r2d2.txt
```

I keep getting an error saying protections for unixcourse are correct however, the protection on fileAsst does not allow members of my group to access them, but it should.
I am going by the u(user), g(group),o(other),a(all) + adds permission and - removes permission. 4 is read 2 is write and 1 is execute.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance~!

Comment: Please edit your question to make a few things more clear (I figured it out, but others seeking a similar question might not): You started the question wtih a block of code, but did not explain _what_ that block of code was. Put a leading explaination such as "I have a task to give certain files/directories certain permissions (protections). Here is the list and the permissions they should have ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fileAsst` is a directory whose permissions are 740. This means that members of the group (apart from the owner) can read the content of `fileAsst`, but can't make `fileAsst` their current directory. This has the weird consequence that they can list the files in `fileAsst`, but can't see those files' details.

I created `fileAsst` at home, copied the `passwd` file to it and gave it these permissions. As a result:

```
$ ls -l fileAsst/
ls: cannot access 'fileAsst/passwd': Permission denied
total 0
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? passwd
```

You need to give `fileAsst` execute permissions as a minimum, i.e. 750 or 770.

Comment: I see. Will check on that, thank you! Also do you know what " look through the directory via ls" mean? I was thinking that it means reading a file but not writing or executing.

Comment: It probably means "run `ls FileAsst`". This lists the files in `FileAsst`.

Comment: @Timothy: `ls` is the command to list files/directories. "... look through via ls ...", in context, appears to mean "you should be able to display the directory listing with the `ls` command". (Also note, in a un\*x world, we call these things 'file permissions', not 'protections'.)